prove real analysis series question: $\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}a_i^2b_i^2 < \infty $
Suppose, $a_k$ and $b_k$ is non-negative sequences. $a_k$ decreasing, $\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}a_i $ diverge to $\infty$, and $\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}a_i^2$ converge.
For $\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}a_i^2b_i^2 < \infty$ to hold, what conditions must sequence $b_k$ satisfy?
My answer: $b_k$ it only need to be bounded sequence (not sure if it correct or how to prove). But this is not required for $b_k$, so what is?
(English not my language, please excuse.)

If $a_k = k^{-1}$ and $b_k = k^{1/3}$, then $\sum a_i$ diverges, $\sum a_i^2$ converges, and $\sum a_i^2 b_i^2$ converges although $b_k$ is unbounded.

@aschepler then what condition needs to be imposed on $b_k$? are there even any?

If $b_k$ is bounded, the comparison test shows $\sum a_k^2 b_k^2$ converges.  However, of course this condition is not necessary (examples are easy to construct).
EDIT: $a_k^2 b_k^2$ can be any sequence of positive numbers (to make $a_k^2 b_k^2 = c_k$, just take $b_k = \sqrt{c_k/a_k^2}$.  So for a necessary condition, just take any necessary condition for $\sum_k c_k$ to converge and apply it to $c_k = a_k^2 b_k^2$.  For example, one necessary condition is that $a_k b_k$ is bounded.

what is necessary then? is there any?
